# how to send multipart http requests containing both image and other json body in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, mobile-development

I am trying to submit a sign up process that contains both the profile image and the user information as body with http package in flutter

I have tried using the multipart request approach both cant seem to send both image and other request body at once to one endpoint

Comment: Please show what you have already tried - and why it isn't working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the example code from which you can understand how a multipart request is sent to the server.**

```
imagePath = # image picked from image_picker

var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', );

request.fields['name'] = 'User Name';
request.fields['email'] = 'test@example.com';

request.files.add(
  await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('profile', imagePath,),
);

request.headers.addAll({
    # headers
});

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
var responseBytes = await response.stream.toBytes();
var responseString = utf8.decode(responseBytes);
final result = jsonDecode(responseString);
print(result);
```

I hope this will help you. If you are still unsure, I recommend the `Dio` plugin. An example is [here](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#sending-formdata)